# Mac Ruby stuck on 2.6.3p62

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am trying to update ruby to 2.7.1 on my mac, but every time I do rbenv global 2.7.1; ruby -v always shows 2.6.3.

I even checked with rbenv global and it returned 2.7.1.

Installed ruby via homebrew.

Comment: Run ``rbenv version``. It will tell you the version and from where it's drawing spec.

Comment: I did rbenv version and it says 2.7.1

Comment: You can't install Ruby via Homebrew and expect rbenv to manage it; rbenv is a sandbox manager. Let it install Rubies and manage which is supposed to run. Read the [rbenv docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using zsh then probably you can do the following

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

then open a new terminal and check again.

Comment: That worked, however when I restart my terminal it goes back to 2.6.3

Comment: can you run the command on the terminal echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' ?
then copy the result of the terminal and add it to your ~/.zshrc file
then run the command 
source ~/.zshrc